# filter an array by its element

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

Below is the array inside loop:
I want to filter this array by  [date-begin] and [date-end] 
For eg if I post startdate = 2015-06-29 and enddate = 2015-08-29
then array data between this range should come.

I tried:

```
1. array_slice 
2.foreach(range ($startdate,$enddate) as $data){
                            echo "Age: {$data}<br />";
                        }
Array
(
    [name] => MCLE 201
    [date-begin] => 2015-06-29
    [date-end] => 2015-06-29

)
Array
(
    [name] => MCLE 201
    [date-begin] => 2015-07-29
    [date-end] => 2015-07-29

)
Array
(
    [name] => MCLE 201
    [date-begin] => 2015-08-29
    [date-end] => 2015-08-29

)
Array
(
    [name] => MCLE 201
    [date-begin] => 2015-09-29
    [date-end] => 2015-09-29

)
```

Comment: have a look on array_filter or try foreach

Answer (score 1):

@Aashi you can do it with foreach() like below:

```
<?php
  $yourArray = array(
                array(
                    "name" => "MCLE 201",
                    "date-begin" => "2015-06-29",
                    "date-end" => "2015-06-29"

                ),
                array(
                    "name" => "MCLE 201",
                    "date-begin" => "2015-07-29",
                    "date-end" => "2015-07-29"

                ),
                array(
                    "name" => "MCLE 201",
                    "date-begin" => "2015-08-29",
                    "date-end" => "2015-08-29"

                ),
                array(
                    "name" => "MCLE 201",
                    "date-begin" => "2015-09-29",
                    "date-end" => "2015-09-29"

                )
              );
$startdate = "2015-06-29";
$enddate = "2015-08-29";
$filteredArr = array();
foreach($yourArray as $value) {
      if($startdate <= $value["date-begin"] && $enddate >= $value["date-end"]){
        $filteredArr[] = $value;
      }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($filteredArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$filterArray = array();
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
    if(strtotime($val['date-begin']) >= strtotime($postedDateBegin) && strtotime($val['date-end']) <= strtotime($postedDateEnd)){
        $filterArray[] = $val;
    }
}
```

[Click here to check output](https://3v4l.org/nK4BP)

Comment: @Aashi, If this worked, can you accept this as answer. It is a good practice to encourage others developers too. Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

this is proper solution for you question !

```
function date_is_between($start_date, $end_date, $date){
    $start_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($start_date));
    $end_date  = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($end_date));
    $date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));
    $match = FALSE;

    if (($date => $start_date) && ($date <= $end_date))
        $match = TRUE;

    return $match;
}

function date_between($element, $start_date, $end_date)
{
    $match = FALSE

        if(date_is_between($element['date-begin'],  $element['date-end'], $element['date-begin']) && date_is_between($element['date-begin'],  $element['date-end'], $element['date-end']))
            $match = TRUE;

    return $match;
}

$filter_array = array_filter($data, "date_between");
```